# Can we combine 2 filters in R?

Tags: r

recently I am thinking about that can 2 filter functions combine into 1 filter?

For example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
a <- flights %>% filter(month == 1)
b <- flights %>% filter(day == 1)
```

Now, a is filtering flights that in Jan, and b on 1st.
I want to combine the filter a & b, which means I want to find that flights that are 1st Jan.
Except for

```
flights %>% filter(month == 1 & day == 1)
```

Can we find a and b first, and combine 2 filters in 1, because sometimes I need to filter lots of information, and I think if I can filter it separately first will be easier. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need `flights %>% filter(month == 1 | day == 1)`  which is same as `unique(rbind(a, b))`

Comment: I tried to run unique(rbind(a, b)), however, to result became all flights in Jan, and I want to find out the flights that are 1st Jan. Is there any way to do this without using flights %>% filter(month == 1 | day == 1)? Many thanks

Comment: Isn't this flights on 1st Jan? `flights %>% filter(month == 1 & day == 1)` What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ohh wait do you want to find flights on 1st Jan using `a` and `b` in that case you can do `intersect(a, b)`

Comment: yes, exactly. However, can we use intersect if we have more than two elements? thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for where the dot notation defines a function:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- . %>% filter(cyl == 4)  # or a <- function(x) filter(x, cyl == 4)
b <- . %>% filter(gear == 4)

mtcars %>% a %>% b
```

giving those rows for which `cyl` is 4 and `gear` is 4:

```
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Also note that filtering successively as we do here is more efficient than filtering each condition separately and then combining them.  In the first case at each step we are reducing the size of the data but in the second we are dealing with the full data at each filtering step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::intersect`.

```
a1 <- flights %>% filter(month == 1)
a2 <- flights %>% filter(day == 1)
result1 <- dplyr::intersect(a1, a2)
nrow(result1)
#[1] 842
```

This is same as doing :

```
nrow(flights %>% filter(month == 1 & day == 1))
#[1] 842
```

If you have more than 2 conditions use it with `Reduce` :

```
a3 <- flights %>% filter(dep_delay == 2)
result2 <- Reduce(dplyr::intersect, list(a1, a2, a3))
nrow(result2)
#[1] 23
```

is same as

```
nrow(flights %>% filter(month == 1 & day == 1 & dep_delay == 2))
#[1] 23
```